# Undefined index: command

Tags: php, javascript, html

These are my codes And i'm getting error

> Notice: Undefined index: command in E:\xampp\htdocs\Shop_cart\products.php on line 17

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function addtocart(pid){
document.form1.productid.value=pid;
document.form1.command.value='add';
document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form name="form1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(1)" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
$pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
addtocart($pid,1);
header("location:shoppingcart.php");
exit();
```

Comment: There are 3.000+ questions like this. Use the search!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP code add `isset` check to the condition:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0 ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
```

to

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
```

Comment: is your answer the same below? ..

Comment: @DrixsonOseña yes it is......probably that answer got submitted while I was typing mine

Answer (score 0):

Same to other answer but I would literally proceed something like this for security purposes and better layout of my code.

```
//Check if request has been made
if (isset($_REQUEST['command'])){

  //proceed for checking
  if($_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0 )
  {
    //Your code here
  }

}else{
   //redirect or whatsoever
}
```